# Best practice for using threads for records insertion?

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite, jdbc, executorservice

I want to populate the data base table with more than 500 million lines, and I have the below `insert` method:

```
public void insertRecord(Record rec) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if (this.isTableExists(this.TABLE_NAME)) {

        Connection conn = this.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into "+this.TABLE_NAME+" ("+this.NODE_ID_COL+", "+this.LAT_COL+", "+this.LNG_COL+", "+this.XML_PATH_COL+") values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        ps.setString(1, rec.getNodeID());
        ps.setString(2, rec.getLat());
        ps.setString(3, rec.getLng());
        ps.setString(4, rec.getPath());

        ps.addBatch();
        ps.executeBatch();

        ps.close();
        conn.close();

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "insertRecord", "table: ["+this.TABLE_NAME+"] does not exist");
    }

}
```

My questions are, since I will insert a huge number of lines:

1. Should I use threads in the above posted method?
2. What is the best practice for such situation?
3. Is ExecutorService yields petter performance in such situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is very inefficient.
For each record you

1. Get a new connection (if you have a connection pool, this isn't an
   issue)
2. Prepare a new `PreparedStatement`
3. Create a batch of size 1
4. Execute the batch immediately

Instead you should keep a single `PreparedStatement` and execute batches of size 50-100 on it.

After that you can consider multi-threading, if you know what you're doing. Multi-threading isn't magic that makes everything faster.

Comment: what if the batch size is 100, and the i want to insert 102 records, how should i handle the rest of the 2 records for an example??kindly please advice?

Comment: i mean, i do not know how many records i wish to insert in advance, how can i handle this..please advice

Comment: You don't need to know. Just insert all the records that you get, executing the batch at least every 100 inserts. Nothing stops you from executing a smaller batch at the end when there's less than 100 items.

Answer (score 2):

In your insertion method keep an array of Records as a buffer.

After you reach say 100 items, create a `PreparedStatement` and then foreach record call the `addBatch`. After adding all your records call the `executeBatch`.

That will return you an array of what the affected records where for each batch call.

If that's not enough then yes, you should look into `Executors` that run `Runnables` in a queue, each one of them being one insertion (or even a batch of a couple of them).

The thing is that error handling becomes increasingly complex, so try to avoid it `if you can`.

Also using multithreading means execution is asynchronous, so if you have a client waiting for a response, you need to synchronize things carefully.

Comment: There is no need to recreate a prepared statement for each 100 items.

Comment: what if the batch size is 100, and the i want to insert 102 records, how should i handle the rest of the 2 records for an example?or in other words, in case i do not know how many records i want to insert in advance, how can i handle that situation?kindly please advice?

Comment: At the end of the execution, if the buffer is not empty, 'flush' it, doing a foreach on wathever is pending on the array. If this is a daemon that runs forever, put a timeout: flush the buffer when it's full or after n seconds.